# What does a comma mean in my regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

It's surely a simple question for somebody.
I found this pattern for jquery:

```
/^([0-9]{0,12})$/,/^[0-9]{1,12}[\,]{1}(|[0-9]{0,4})$/
```

The

```
/^([0-9]{0,12})$/
```

and

```
/^[0-9]{1,12}[\,]{1}(|[0-9]{0,4})$/
```

I don't understand the pattern.
My only question is and I find nothing via google: What does the comma make?
Is he checking two patterns or does this comma do something special?

---

Here is the link
http://freedns.remdex.info/JQuery-simple-input-validation-plugin-74a.html

So when he accepts arrays it means that he checks whether if one it is true?

Comment: `preg_match` is in PHP, not JQuery.

Comment: where did you found this , provide us a link

Comment: What is a "pattern for jQuery" ?

Comment: The full code is *probably* `[/^...$/,/^...$/]` so it's *probably* just an array of regexes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381358/php-preg-replace-how-to-combine-these-two-preg-statements

Answer (score 3):

Now that you stated your [actual source](http://freedns.remdex.info/JQuery-simple-input-validation-plugin-74a.html) we can come to the conclusion that the full line is:

```
$("#only_int_float").rval([/^([0-9]{0,6})$/,/^[0-9]{1,6}[\.|,]{1}(|[0-9]{0,2})$/]);
```

As you may notice, there's `[` and `]` brackets, which means this is an array. So basically, it would be the same as the following:

```
var regexes = new Array(
    /^([0-9]{0,6})$/, 
    /^[0-9]{1,6}[\.|,]{1}(|[0-9]{0,2})$/
);
$("#only_int_float").rval(regexes);
```

In the same source, you can find the code:

```
$.each(
    regularExpression,
    function( intIndex, objValue ){ 
        var re = new RegExp(objValue);                                        
        if((re.exec(instance.value) || instance.value == '') && allOk == false)
        {
            allOk = true;                                   
        } 
    }
);
```

Which means "for each regex in the variable `regularExpression`, run the following function (where it checks if the regex matches).

`allOk` clearly gets set to true if there's just one match, so you can use this array as an `OR` statement (if regex #1 doesn't match, check regex2 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

if this is for PHP

**preg_replace accepts arrays as arguments**

this

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\\r\\n!.,\'“”;’?-\s+]/', ' ', $str);
$str=preg_replace('/\s+\S{1,2}(?!\S)|(?<!\S)\S{1,2}\s+/', '', $str);
```

is equalnt to

```
str = preg_replace(array('/^([0-9]{0,12})$/','/^[0-9]{1,12}[\,]{1}(|[0-9]{0,4})$/'), array(' ', ''), $str);
```

Comment: I think you're missing some quotation marks in some of your code